# How to disable sap.m.Select when only one selection item left

Tags: sapui5

I made an example for this question with the following logic:
A dropdown (`sap.m.Select`) has 2 options:
[image: 2 Options]
But whenever a checkbox above it is checked it only has one option left:
[image: 1 Option]
In that case I don't need any of this anymore:
[image: Unnecessary stuff]
So I found out, that the property `editable="false"` does exactly what I want in this case:
[image: editable="false"]

...but I don't know how to set `editable` dynamically depending on the current number of options.

Here's the full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mb0h8v1s/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a `JSONModel` you can say something like

```xml
editable="{= ${options>/arr1}.length > 1 }"
```

This is called [Expression Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) and lets you use basic JavaScript within your binding.`

---

This assumes that you always use the same list and change the content of your list once the `CheckBox` is triggered and not rebind the list.

Answer (score 1):

View:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>SAPUI5</title>
<script src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>

<script id="myView" type="ui5/xmlview">
  <mvc:View controllerName="MyController" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns:layout="sap.ui.commons.layout">
    <Shell>
    <Page id="mainPage" showHeader="false">
    <FlexBox id="flex" justifyContent="Center" alignItems="Center" direction="Column">
    <CheckBox 
        text="Only 1 option" 
      selected="{path:'options>/cbx_val'}"
    />
   
    </FlexBox>
    </Page>
    </Shell>
  </mvc:View>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
 sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
   "use strict";
   sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
     onInit: function() {
       console.log("INITIALIZING!");
       var arr1 = [{
         id: "1",
         name: "1st option"
       }];
       var arr2 = arr1.concat([{
         id: "2",
         name: "2nd option"
       }]);
       var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
         cbx_val: false,
         arr1: arr1,
         arr2: arr2
       });
       this.getView().setModel(oModel, "options");

       var selectVal = new sap.m.Select({
         id: "selectField",
         selectedKey: '',
         editable: true,
         enabled: "{= !${options>/cbx_val}}"
       });

       var selectLbl = new sap.m.Label({
         text: "Select:",
         labelFor: selectVal,
       });

       var selectLogicListener = new sap.m.Text({
         visible: false,
         text: {
           parts: ['options>/cbx_val'],
           formatter: function(bVal) {
               var result = "options>/arr2";
               if (bVal) {
                 result = "options>/arr1";
               }
               console.log(result);
             selectVal.bindItems({
               path: result,
               template: new sap.ui.core.Item({
                 key: "{options>id}",
                 text: "{options>name}"
               })
             });
           }
         }
       });

       this.byId("flex").addItem(selectLbl);
       this.byId("flex").addItem(selectVal);
       this.byId("flex").addItem(selectLogicListener);
     }
   });
   sap.ui.xmlview({
     viewContent: jQuery("#myView").html()
   }).placeAt("content");

 });
```